# I would like to use Rewrite rule to clear my url

Tags: php, mysql, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, clean-urls

I would like to clear my url by using RewriteRule at .htacces.

I would like to change **/product/detail.php?id=red-shirt** to something like this **/product/red-shirt**.

I tried to use this **RewriteRule ^/?product/([^/d]+)/?$ /product/detail.php?id=$1 [L,QSA]** but it does not work.

Comment: Shouldn't that be `\d` instead of `/d`?

Comment: Please **edit** your question and define "does not work". Do you get an error (404, 500), what is the error in the server log if any is generated, what url do you end up with in the browser. Does your computer explode in a cloud of unicorns when you go to that url? Also please note that there is a format as code button in the editor (button with `{}` on it). Select your code and click that button.

Comment: In addition to @Sumurai8 's comment, enable rewrite log and check its content.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're getting 404 because your regex is wrong. Use this rule to fix this:

```
# If the request is not for a valid directory
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
# If the request is not for a valid file
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^product/([^/]+)/?$ /product/detail.php?id=$1 [L,NC,QSA]
```

Answer (score 0):

I will all the time get 404 Error.
If I change /d to \d I will get interal server error 500